# How can I std::getline() a string?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

Let say I have this string

```
string myString = "This is a test string:value1/value2/value3/"
```

How can I do something like this:

```
getline (myString, temp, '/');
```

I was thinking about `output << myString` to a file, and then using 
`getline (output, temp, '/')` as usual, but I think there should be other ways.
Thanks, please help me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`getline` extracts from a stream; so you want to put your string into a [string-stream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream):

```
#include <sstream>

std::stringstream ss(myString);
getline(ss, temp, '/');
```